# «Между улиц» или «между улицами»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, падежи, выбор

*«Между улиц»* или *«между улицами (такими-то)»?*

Comment: Между улиц = промеж улиц. "Между нас пошел слух", но не "между нами пошел слух".  Хотя можно и так, наверное.

Comment: Между улиц (**куда**) был направлен прицел авиации. Между улицами (**где**) были переулки. Между глаз (куда) пришёлся удар, между глазами (где) сидела муха.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Предпочтителен вариант ***между улицами***. В разговорной речи допустим вариант ***между улиц***.

> [**МЕЖДУ,**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83) ***предлог.** кем-чем, (разг.) кого-чего (с двумя сущ. ед. или мн., соединёнными союзом и, или с одним сущ. мн., а также со сл.* собой). **1.** Указывает на пространственное положение кого-, чего-л. среди других лиц, предметов, явлений и т. п. или на место свершения какого-л. действия в окружении кого-, чего-л.; среди. *Сидеть м. двумя мужчинами; (разг.; двух мужчин). Морщина м. бровями (разг.; м. бровей). Пролегать м. деревьями (разг.; деревьев). Расположиться м. двумя озерами (разг.; двух озер). Положить м. листами (разг.; листов) книги.*

[**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%96%D0%94%D0%A3%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC)

> Сегодня нормативно: *между чем (между столами, между гаражами). Между чего* – устаревающий вариант.

В [**Нацкорпусе русского языка**](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&g=i_doc&dpp=10&spp=50&text=lexform&req=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8&kwsz=5&p=1&mode=main&sr=1&spd=10&nodia=1&out=normal) вариант ***между улиц*** не встретился, но есть 28 документов с ***между улицами***, например:

*Его и сейчас можно видеть, один из четырех на мысочке **между улицами Осипенко и Озерной***. [Анатолий Найман. Рассказы о Анне Ахматовой (1986-1987)]

*Было человек пять-шесть в то время в Берлине, которые попадались Белому вечерами **между улицами Пассауэр, Аугсбургер, Прагер и Гейсберг***. [Н. Н. Берберова. Курсив мой (1960-1966)]